# collapse not working in siderbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i added a `data-toggle="collapse"` to a link in nav side bar , and when link is clicked `>` should change to `v` ,when another tab is clicked it should change to `>`
    but looks like collapse functionality is not working . in CSS i have the code to change icons  , Can someone pint out the issue here
    Thanks in advance

Below is the code snippet :-

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
      <nav class="nav-sidebar">
        <ul class="nav tabs">
          <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#tab1">tab1</a></li>
          <li class=""><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#tab2"> Tab2</a></li>
          <li class=""><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#tab3"> Tab3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <!-- tab content -->
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9 tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active text-style collapse in" id="tab1">
        <p> This is Tab1 content </p>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane text-style collapse" id="tab2">
        <p> This is Tab2 content </p>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane text-style collapse" id="tab3">
        <p> This is Tab3 content </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

in css file

```
.nav-sidebar a:after {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  content: "\e114";
  float: right;
  color: grey;
}

.nav-sidebar a.collapsed:after {
  content: "\e080";
}
```

Comment: Which version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: Did any of the answers below help? If not, please let us know why and we'll be happy to answer any questions or doubts you may have.

Comment: Yes below helped Yass

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things here.  You don't need to use the collapse with this as you are using bootstrap's tabs so you can scratch the collapse.  So you don't need to put the data-target and data-toggle in the href's as bootstraps tabs will take care of this you just need to use `data-toggle="tab"` and it will toggle the tab by the href value.  Then you can remove the collapse class from your tab panes as well.  That being said bootstap will change the active class of the li when you click on the link so you can change your after content from there. So it will look like so:

Here is a fiddle showing you the changes [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/tuz7ogy7/)

Revised Html:

```
<ul class="nav tabs">
<li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">Tab 3</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
<!-- tab content -->
<div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9 tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="tab1">
<p> This is Tab1 content  </p>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2">
<p> This is Tab2 content  </p>    
</div>
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab3">
<p> This is Tab3 content  </p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Revised Css:

```
.nav-sidebar a:after{
  content: "\e114";
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  color: grey;
  float: right;
}
.nav-sidebar li.active a:after{
  content: "\e080";
}
```